# Log errors in one of my php script to specified logfile

Tags: php

If I run following php file

```
<?php
$str = 'he;
echo $str;
?>
```

it will log a parse error to standard apache log file.
I can specify a logfile in php.ini but that would change logfile for all php scripts.

Is it possible to log errors from specific script to a particular log file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time. I also suggest you review your own questions when posting them: the code snippet you mention was not even visible!

Comment: Alvaro, thanks. saw it just now. been using SO for long time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using `.htaccess` directive in conjunction with `<Files>`:

```
<Files something.php>
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_value error_log /path/to/your/error.log
</Files>

<Files something_else.php>
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_value error_log /path/to/your/other_error.log
</Files>
```

Also, make sure you have PHP installed as Apache module, else it won't work.

Comment: This is not a per-file setting :-?

Comment: Hi Ondrej, my first guess was same. I tried that but it's not working. I created .htaccess file in my directory containing php scripts. Contents of .htaccess are:
"php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  logfile.txt

Comment: @Álvaro Yeah, sorry, did read it too hastily. Fixed.

Comment: @vivek.m Are you running PHP as CGI or module? Is your .htaccess even working? Check if you can override any settings (`AllowOverride All`) in that certain directory.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP/5.3.0 and greater, you can create [[PATH=] sections](http://es.php.net/manual/en/ini.sections.php#ini.per-path) in your php.ini file.

You mention something about Apache. If you are running PHP as Apache module, you can use the [php_value](http://es.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) directive inside standard Apache containers like [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/es/mod/core.html#files).

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.3 it is possible to bind a setting in php.ini to a certein path through usage of [PATH](http://%5BPATH=/home/site/public/secure%5D).

> this section allows you to define a set of php.ini directives that
>   will take effect when a script runs from the named path.